# MySQL foreign key to auto_increment field

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm trying to create this table :

```
CREATE TABLE INFORMEPERICIAL (
INFORME_NO INT(3),
PRIMARY KEY (INFORME_NO),
DATEEMISIO DATE NOT NULL,
IMPORTCOBERT DECIMAL(8,2),
PERIT_NO INT(3) NOT NULL,
INFORME VARCHAR(200),
RESULTATPERITATGE  VARCHAR(20),
 CONSTRAINT RESULTATPERITATGE_CK CHECK (RESULTATPERITATGE IN ('COBERT_TOTAL','COBERT_PARCIAL','SENSE_COBERTURA','REPARAT')),
ESTATINFORME  VARCHAR(20),
 CONSTRAINT ESTATINFORME_CK CHECK ESTATINFORME IN ('PENDENT','TANCAT'),
 CONSTRAINT INFORMEPERICIAL_FK_PERIT FOREIGN KEY (PERIT_NO) REFERENCES PERIT (NUMERO),
 CONSTRAINT INFORMEPERICIAL_CK_INFORME_NO_NUM_POSITIU CHECK (INFORME_NO > 0)
);
```

But, i'm having troubles with the foreign key.

This is my ok-formed "Perit" table" :

```
CREATE TABLE PERIT (
COGNOM1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
COGNOM2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
DATANAIX DATE NOT NULL,
NOM VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
NIF VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
LOGIN VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PASSWORDMD5  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
NUMERO INT(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (NUMERO)
);
```

I can't undesrtand why I'm getting the error 1005, the field-types are equals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is here:

```
CONSTRAINT ESTATINFORME_CK CHECK ESTATINFORME IN ('PENDENT','TANCAT'),
```

Wrap the condition in parentheses:

```
CONSTRAINT ESTATINFORME_CK CHECK (ESTATINFORME IN ('PENDENT','TANCAT')),
```